# Botframework V4: Video attachment on messenger

Tags: c#, botframework, messenger, video-card

Hi i tried all these methods of attaching a video to a bot. All of them are working fine in bot emulator. But when i publish it to messenger it is throwing an exception . (I can't see the exception by the way i just know because of the message. Is there a way to see or log exceptions?). Is video card not supported in messenger? Or is youtube not supported as an url link?

Here are the codes:

```
     AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
            reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            reply.Attachments.Add(GetVideoCard().ToAttachment());
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.NextAsync();
        });

////////////////

   private static VideoCard GetVideoCard()
    {
        var videoCard = new VideoCard
        {
            Title = "Budgeting Introduction",
            Subtitle = "by Finko",

            Media = new List<MediaUrl>
            {
                new MediaUrl()
                {
                    Url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLo1geVokhA",
                },
            },
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>
            {
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = "Learn More at Finko.PH",
                    Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                    Value = "https://m-moreno.wixsite.com/finkoph?fbclid=IwAR1NVtlyKfzZ0mYFIWva8L-d8TUv4KFpt_m1i1ij3raT-pbWr2c3-kqzB2Q",
                },
            },
        };

        return videoCard;
    }
```

and

```
    AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var activity = stepContext.Context.Activity;
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(CreateResponse(activity, CreateVideoCardAttacment()));
            return await stepContext.NextAsync();
        });

////////////////////////

   private Activity CreateResponse(Activity activity, Attachment attachment)
    {
        var response = activity.CreateReply();
        response.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { attachment };
        return response;
    }

    private Attachment CreateVideoCardAttacment()
    {
        return new VideoCard()
        {
            Title = "Are you a Seafarer? OFW? FREE PERSONAL FINANCIAL ADVICE HERE!!",
            Media = new List<MediaUrl>()
            {
                new MediaUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLo1geVokhA")
            },
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                    Title = "Learn More at Finko.PH",
                    Value = "https://m-moreno.wixsite.com/finkoph?fbclid=IwAR1NVtlyKfzZ0mYFIWva8L-d8TUv4KFpt_m1i1ij3raT-pbWr2c3-kqzB2Q"
                }
            },
            Subtitle = "by Finko.Ph",
            Text = "Are you tired of getting bogus financial advice? Tired of having 'kape' just to find out it was networking, or a pyramid scheme? Tired of scouring the internet for HOURS but not finding what you're looking for? We're here to help! We give financial advice and will educate you on financial literacy topics, ABSOLUTELY FREE!!"
        }.ToAttachment();
    }
```

and

```
       Activity reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
            var card = new VideoCard
            {
                Title = "Finko.ph",
                Media = new List<MediaUrl>()
                {
                    new MediaUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLo1geVokhA")
                },
                Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
                {
                    new CardAction()
                    {
                        Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                        Title = "Learn More at Finko.PH",
                        Value = "https://m-moreno.wixsite.com/finkoph?fbclid=IwAR1NVtlyKfzZ0mYFIWva8L-d8TUv4KFpt_m1i1ij3raT-pbWr2c3-kqzB2Q"
                    }
                },
            };
            reply.Attachments.Add(card.ToAttachment());
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply);
            return await stepContext.NextAsync();
```

and

```
    var reply1 = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
            var attachment1 = new Attachment
            {
                ContentUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLo1geVokhA",
                ContentType = "video/mp4",
                Name = "imageName1",
            };
            reply1.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { attachment1 };
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply1, cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.NextAsync();
```

All of these codes are working in bot emulator but not in messenger. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Have you tried debugging locally? https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/

Comment: Thank you sir unfortunately ngrok is blocked here.

Answer (score 0):

The BotFramework converts Video Cards into Media Templates for Facebook Messenger, and per Facebook's Developer documentation, media templates do not allow any external URLs, only those on Facebook. You must either upload the video to Facebook or provide a URL directly to the mp4 file which, unfortunately, YouTube doesn't make readily available.

For more details, take a look at Facebooks documentation regarding [Media Templates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/media/).

Comment: Ohh thank you. I will try a facebook link. But i tried this direct link though "http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" and still not working.

Comment: I think that may have to do with the length of the video. This [video link](https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/783d/d57287a5-185f-4df9-aa08-fcab699a783d/IC18WorldChampionshipIntro2.mp4) works just fine.

Comment: Yep tried that link it is working. I wonder what is the minimum required length of the video? will mark your answer once i tested the facebook video link.

Comment: Per Facebook's documentation on [attachments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/), the max upload size is 25MB.

Comment: Were you able to get it to work with a Facebook link?